# sort a list of maps according to a list elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this sorted list

```
@days ["mon", "tue", "wen", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
```

and I have a list of maps such as

```
[%{day: "sat"}, %{day: "tue"}, %{day: "fri"}]
```

I am trying to sort the list of maps according to days, I have tried `Enum.sort_by/2` but I am unable to put the right condition. any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want, is to produce a *sorter* with `O(1)` access in the first place

```
iex||1 ▸ days = ["mon", "tue", "wen", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
["mon", "tue", "wen", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
iex||2 ▸ days_idx = days |> Enum.zip(1..7) |> Map.new()
```

Now sorting the original list would be as easy as

```
iex||3 ▸ Enum.sort_by(
...||3 ▸   [%{day: "sat"}, %{day: "tue"}, %{day: "fri"}],
...||3 ▸   &days_idx[&1[:day]])

#⇒ [%{day: "tue"}, %{day: "fri"}, %{day: "sat"}]
```

Comment: Happy new year Aleksei! and thank you.

Comment: btw what if the unsorted list does not implement the Access behaviour for the map?

Comment: You spilled some stuff on your prompt 

Comment: I produde the map myself, see the 1st iteration.